# Bugzilla configuration , Software error

Tags: bugzilla

I installed Bugzilla on centos server ,But after installation it show error like below .I googled lot nothing works`

> Software error:
>
> The /var/lib/bugzilla/data/params file does not exist. You probably
>   need to run checksetup.pl. at Bugzilla/Config.pm line 344. Compilation
>   failed in require at /usr/share/bugzilla/index.cgi line 34. BEGIN
>   failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/bugzilla/index.cgi line 34.

`

Comment: Have you tried running `checksetup.pl`?

Comment: I already tried it

Comment: facing same error